# Javafx - Bind the background task with Scene

Tags: javafx

My application having the two Screens.

**Screen-1:**
It's having two buttons and one Label

1) *Download:*
    If we click on this, then we will start the downloading process but we still in screen1 and allow you to access the "Navigate" control.

2) *Navigate:* If we click on this, Then we will redirect to the screen-2.

**Screen-2:**

1)Back: If we click on this, then we will back to the Screen-1.

While downloading process, I want to allow the user to access the other controls as well. If we started the download process and navigates to some other screen and redirects to the download screen, then we will show the current downloading progress instead of opening it as fresh. For this, I implemented like following. I created one class for implementing this download process but I am unable to update the UI of the screen from that class. Please help me on this.

```
Screen-1
```

public class MainsceneController implements Initializable {

```
@FXML
Button Download, Navigate;
@FXML
Label percentage;
@FXML
HBox progTag;
SyncService service = new SyncService(MainsceneController.this);

/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
}

@FXML
void DownlaodManager() {
    service.downloadProjectFiles();
}

@FXML
void Naviagtion() {
    URL location = SecondSceneController.class.getResource("SecondScene.fxml");
    ViewManager.getInstance().setView(location);
}
```

}

```
Screen-2:
```

public class SecondSceneController implements Initializable {

```
/**
 * Initializes the controller class.
 */
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
}

@FXML
void goBack() {
    URL location = MainsceneController.class.getResource("mainscene.fxml");
    ViewManager.getInstance().setView(location);
}
```

}

```
Background downloading task
```

public class SyncService {

```
long currentDownload, totalFileSize;
MainsceneController controller;
DownloadingFilesTask downloadingFilesTask;

public SyncService(MainsceneController controller) {
    this.controller = controller;
    downloadingFilesTask = new DownloadingFilesTask();
}
public void downloadProjectFiles() throws IOException {
    DownloadingFilesTask downloadingFilesTask = new DownloadingFilesTask();

    downloadingFilesTask.progressProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> ov, Number oldProgress, Number newProgress) {
            System.out.println("Progress changed");
            controller.percentage.setText("Progress changed:" + currentDownload);
        }
    });

    downloadingFilesTask.stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> source, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
            if (newState.equals(Worker.State.SUCCEEDED)) {
                System.err.println("Completed downloading files");
                controller.percentage.setText("Progress changed:" + currentDownload);
            }
        }
    });

    //progress listeners.
    ProgressBar bar = new ProgressBar();
    bar.progressProperty().bind(downloadingFilesTask.progressProperty());
    bar.visibleProperty().bind(downloadingFilesTask.runningProperty());
    controller.progTag.getChildren().clear();
    controller.progTag.getChildren().add(bar);

    new Thread(downloadingFilesTask).start();
}

class DownloadingFilesTask extends Task<Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void call() throws Exception {

        try {
            String fullUrl = "http://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/absprod/media/25/manuals/53454a73d9eda$$53454a73d9f571397049971.mp4";
            String destLocation = "C:\\Users\\naresh.repalle\\Desktop\\ABS Test\\53454a73d9eda$$53454a73d9f571397049971.mp4";
            File destFile = new File(destLocation);

            URL downloadingUrl = new URL(fullUrl);
            RandomAccessFile file = null;
            InputStream stream = null;
            int downloaded = 0;
            int size = -1;


            try {
                // Open connection to URL.
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) downloadingUrl.openConnection();

                // Specify what portion of file to download.
                connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + downloaded + "-");
                connection.setConnectTimeout(10 * 1000);
                connection.setReadTimeout(10 * 1000);
                // Connect to server.
                connection.connect();


                // Make sure response code is in the 200 range.
                if (connection.getResponseCode() / 100 != 2) {
                    System.err.println("Wrong response code while downloading file." + connection.getResponseCode());
                }

                // Check for valid content length.
                int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
                if (contentLength < 1) {
                    System.err.println("Wrong file size while downloading file." + contentLength);
                }

                /*
                 * Set the size for this download if it hasn't been already set.
                 */
                if (size == -1) {
                    size = contentLength;
                }

                totalFileSize = size;

                // Open file and seek to the end of it.
                file = new RandomAccessFile(destFile, "rw");
                file.seek(downloaded);

                stream = connection.getInputStream();
                int MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;

                while (true) {
                    /*
                     * Size buffer according to how much of the file is left to download.
                     */
                    byte buffer[];
                    if (size - downloaded > MAX_BUFFER_SIZE) {
                        buffer = new byte[MAX_BUFFER_SIZE];
                    } else {
                        buffer = new byte[size - downloaded];
                    }

                    // Read from server into buffer.
                    int read = stream.read(buffer);

                    if (read == -1) {
                        System.out.println("read: " + read);
                        break;
                    }


                    // Write buffer to file.
                    file.write(buffer, 0, read);
                    downloaded += read;
                    currentDownload = downloaded;
                    stateChanged();

                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println("Exception in Downloading file: " + e.toString());
            } finally {
                /*
                 * Change status to complete if this point was reached because downloading
                 * has finished.
                 */
                // Close file.
                if (file != null) {
                    try {
                        file.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                    }
                }

                // Close connection to server.
                if (stream != null) {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.err.println("exception in downloading: " + e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println("Unable to download file: " + ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void stateChanged() {
        updateProgress(currentDownload, totalFileSize);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Is it clear to all who are trying to help me, What I am asking? If no, Please comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SyncService doesn't need to reload the FXML; it just needs to communicate with the existing controller. A simple way to do this would be to just pass a reference to SyncService's constructor:

```
public class SyncService {
    MainSceneController controller ;
    public SyncService(MainSceneController controller) {
        this.controller = controller ;
    }

    // ...
    public void downloadProjectFiles() throws IOException {
        DownloadingFilesTask downloadingFilesTask = new DownloadingFilesTask();

//      Remove the following:

//      URL location = MainsceneController.class.getResource("mainscene.fxml");

//      FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader();
//      fxmlLoader.setLocation(location);
//      fxmlLoader.setBuilderFactory(new JavaFXBuilderFactory());

//      final AnchorPane root = (AnchorPane) fxmlLoader.load(location.openStream());

      //get the controller
//      final MainsceneController controller = (MainsceneController) fxmlLoader.getController();

//       Then code as before
//       ...
    }
}
```

I think I would actually do it differently: I don't like the strong coupling between the SyncService and the MainSceneController. I would initialize the progress bar in the MainSceneController, expose the progress as a property in the SyncService and bind to it in the controller. But you should be able to use the simpler approach to get it working.

Comment: I was removed and integrated the code as you said. The UI was updated if we clicks on the download button.While downloading, if we click on the Navigate button then it redirects to the scene-2. Now If we click on the back button in screen-2 then it was come back to the screen-1. Here the UI was not updated with the downloading process but background process was still running. How do we handle this?

Comment: In screen-2, If we clicks on the Back button then I will reload the screen-1. Please see the code. Is it right way?

Comment: If the ViewManager loads a new instance from the FXML file, then of course it won't be observing the progress of the SyncService. Since you really want to go back to the same view, it probably makes sense to rewrite the ViewManager to only ever load each FXML file once.

Comment: Yes, I want to back to the same view. Could you please help me on this. How to implement the functionality which loads fxml file once. This is the  viewmanager class please refer it http://paste.org/71939

Comment: Create a `Map<URL, Parent>`. In the `setView(...)` method, first check to see if a `Parent` already exists for the specified URL, and use it if it does. If not, create one as you currently do, and store it in the map. You need to think about whether caching the views like this is really the functionality you want for your application; for the part you've shown it looks right but it's a business logic decision that affects the entire application.

Comment: I did(http://paste.org/71941) as you said, But I got this exception http://paste.org/71942. Please check it once

Comment: Finally,It's working. I saved scene instead of Parent in the Map. If I save the Parent then I got an exception as mentioned above. Thanks a lot for your valuable help.

Comment: you gave me the one suggestion to implement the functionality as "I would initialize the progress bar in the MainSceneController, expose the progress as a property in the SyncService and bind to it in the controller." But I am not getting how to bind the progress-bar in SyncService to progress-bar in MainSceneController. Please could you explain with the code?

Comment: what are the problems If we are loading the views like this?